# Black artifacts around text when loading bitmap into opengl texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec

I am overlaying text on an image and then loading the image into a OpenGL texture. From there encoding the opengl surface to mp4 using MediaCodec.

Here is an example of an image I am loading into a texture then encoding to mp4. 
[image: Bitmap being uploaded to texture]

But after encoding the OpenGl surface to mp4 using MediaCodec I have black artifacts around the text. Like so:

[image: Encoded mp4 screenshot]

This is basically how I am loading bmp into a texture and displaying it.

```
// Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
//Also have tried this
//GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, mWidth, mHeight, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ByteBuffer.wrap(frameData));
onDrawFrame(mInputSurface.textureHandle);

public void onDrawFrame(int textureHandle)
{
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    // Tell OpenGL to use this program when rendering.
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);

    // Set program handles
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "position");
    mTextureCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "inputTextureCoordinate");
    mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "videoFrame");

    // Set the active texture unit to texture unit 0.
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);

    // Bind the texture to this unit.
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle);

    // Tell the texture uniform sampler to use this texture in the shader by binding to texture unit 0.
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);

    drawTriangle(mRectVertices, mRectTextureCoordinates);

}   
    /**
 * Draws a triangle from the given vertex data.
 *
 * @param aTriangleBuffer The buffer containing the vertex data.
 * @param aRectTextureCoordinates
 */
private void drawTriangle(final FloatBuffer aTriangleBuffer, FloatBuffer aRectTextureCoordinates)
{       
    // Pass in the position information
    aTriangleBuffer.position(mPositionOffset);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0, aTriangleBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);        

    // Pass in the color information
    aRectTextureCoordinates.position(mPositionOffset);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0,aRectTextureCoordinates);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordHandle);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Edit:
@BDL
"Does your textures contain an alpha channel?"

The bitmap has an alpha channel. It is encoded as ARGB_8888.
But I have made sure that it is fully opaque with an alpha value of 255 for all pixels.

"Do you have blending enabled?"

I have tried enabling

```
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Nothing changed

Edit 2:

I am setting the viewport to be the same size as the surface used to encode the video.

```
 // Set the OpenGL viewport to the same size as the surface.
 GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
```

But then I tried doubling the width and height

```
 // Set the OpenGL viewport to the same size as the surface.
 GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width*2, height*2);
```

And while only a quarter of the image is showing... there are no more artifacts.

[image: larger viewport example]

Comment: Does your textures contain an alpha channel? Do you have blending enabled?

Comment: @BDL I have added to my question

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes I know. I enabled GL_BLEND

Comment: If what you render to the screen is the same as your first image, then I don't think the issue is in the GLES side of things; I suspect the issue is in the video compression.

Comment: Failing that, what texture filtering mode are you using? If you are using GL_LINEAR then you will be getting samples which are not alpha = 0, or alpha =1 because they will be getting blended around the edges. Make sure you propagate the red color out into the alpha=0 region so that the color blends out correctly.

Comment: @solidpixel I am using GL_NEAREST for min and mag filters

Comment: @BDL 
I have updated my answer. Managed to make the artifacts go away by increasing the viewport size. But now I can't make the full image show

Comment: @solidpixel ^^^

Comment: @Rabbid76        ^^^^^^^^

Comment: I had a similar problem, it would go away after _removing_ `glBlendFunc` or by scaling the image up.

Not  sure what the issue is, whether it is a framework/OS bug or just something that is expected.